# Deleting all comments in a post causes the add comment link to disappear

Tags: bug, comments

As a moderator, when I delete comments in a post, if I delete all the comments manually (not hitting 'purge all', the 'add comment' dialog disappears after I've deleted the last comment, and there is no 'add comment' link to click on.

I've [tested it here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181141/why-is-this-question-not-constructive) on meta to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I see this as a regular user as well. Meant to report it after careful testing it wasn't any Greasemonkey script. Create the first comment on any post, **start to add a new comment** (so the text box is there), then delete your first comment again.

Comment: I've experienced this on my mobile phone as well.

Comment: +1 for finding a bug, though I wonder if it would have been better to do it on non-live data? A comment of mine on that question disappeared into the ether...

Comment: @halfer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seliot/archive/2011/04/25/i-don-t-always-test-my-code-but-when-i-do-i-do-it-in-production.aspx

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd not really a dupe (since there's no answer there), and mine also shows that the 'add comment' link that would normally appear on a post without comments disappears. That's missing from the other. Completeness man, completeness.

Comment: @halfer Also: Remember, Comments are ephemeral. Oh, wait...  I just figured out how to fix the comment problem on Stack Overflow!  Write a bot that randomly deletes all the comments in a post, and then leaves a comment that say, "Comments are Ephemeral." It's GENIUS.

Comment: When that other bug will be fixed your bug will also be fixed, hence the dupe IMO.

Comment: Wow. I found another bug. That's somewhat weird. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181150/flagging-a-post-as-a-duplicate-shows-the-duplicate-banner-even-though-the-questi

Comment: Stop breaking stuff @GeorgeStocker. See, this is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @Bart No, mainly @​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Oded breaks stuff (as in [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180496/180276) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180724/180276)) :P