# Flagging a post as a duplicate shows the duplicate banner even though the question is still open

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

A user helpfully [flagged my post as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181149/deleting-all-comments-in-a-post-causes-the-add-comment-link-to-disappear). I marked it 'helpful'.

Once I did that, the post showed the 'duplicate banner', even though the post itself is still open (never been closed).  It was also within the 5 minute window, so [there's no revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/181149/revisions).  I promise I didn't edit that banner into the post.

If I view the post as a moderator, I see the banner. If I open a new browser in 'incognito' mode, there is no banner.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167987/158667 ? The close vote is still there/active AFAICT.

Comment: Yup. No banner to see for me.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin' I've added the screenshot. It's surprisingly difficult to edit and create screenshots in stock Ubuntu.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker [This is what I'm seeing there](http://i.imgur.com/GuJd4EY.png) at the moment.

Comment: `[status-by-design]` I'm pretty sure. Only you are seeing that. Try deleting the close vote if you can with your superpowers, @GeorgeStocker.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker You asked the question, you see the banner. We don't.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: As stated in Mat's link, the question's owner is the only one who sees that banner while there is an active duplicate close vote on the question. No one else will see it until the question gets closed.

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently this is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167987/158667).  Closing this as a duplicate. The level of meta-ness here is astounding.